# Hibernate doesn't create my Join entry

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

my problem in hibernate is that when I want to insert a member into a community while creating a new community, it's not inserted to DB. Where am I wrong?

My community class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "community")
public class Community extends BaseModel implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3290182848857364839L;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "owner_id", nullable = false)
    private User owner;

    @Column(name = "picture")
    private String picture;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @JoinTable(name = "community_member", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "community_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {
            "user_id", "community_id" }))
    private List<User> members = new ArrayList<User>();

    //getters and setters...
```

And my code:

```
Community community = new Community();
community.setName(name);
community.setDescription(description);
community.setOwner(user);

String fileName = saveFile(file);
community.setPicture(fileName);

community.getMembers().add(user);

this.getHibernateTemplate().save(community);
```

I can see a community is created in the DB, there is a user that already exists in DB, but `community.getMembers().add(user);` doesn't work. It should create a new entry in `community_member` table.

Is it because I didn't create a java class for `community_member` table?

Edit: I added User entity.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User extends BaseModel implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8464105544313686923L;

    @Column(name = "username", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "email", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = true)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "surname", nullable = true)
    private String surname;

    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "rating", nullable = false)
    private Long rating = 0L;

    @Column(name = "picture")
    private String picture;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, mappedBy = "user")
    private UserRole role;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "status", nullable = false)
    private UserStatus status = UserStatus.DEACTIVE;
```

Edit2: Answer shouldn't be like this but here is my solution(workaround) to this problem: I added member to the community after I created community in DB. Then I've updated the community and the member is inserted.

Comment: You don't have to create a class for `community_member`. You say `user` already exists in the DB, did you obtain it through Hibernate? Also do you have a `Community` list mapped on the `User` side? If so can you show the mapping?

Comment: Yes I obtain it through hibernate. When a user logins, I get the user object from DB and put it into his session. After that, I obtain the user object from user's session. does it affect something?

Comment: Show us the mapping on User entity

Comment: You are using a `List` and not a `Set`. Is there a reason you need an indexed collection? I have never tried a many-to-many relationship with an indexed collection and I do not know what the caveats are, perhaps you need to specify `@OrderColumn` on one or both sides.

Comment: @RomanKonoval I didn't map User to Community.

Comment: @JasonC let me try it with Set. I'll let you know if it works or not.

Comment: No, it didn't change anything with Set. Should I map User to Community, too?

Comment: @sedran I may be wrong but you shouldn't have to map both sides, but you could try it. At this point you're beyond my limited knowledge of Hibernate; I'm almost certain the answer is something simpler but I don't know what it is. Sorry I couldn't be of more help. Hopefully somebody else chimes in. You could also try https://forum.hibernate.org if you don't get an answer here.

Comment: You are doing setup for community but are saving transientInstance. Is the code you've provided accurate?

Comment: I'm sorry, I coppied the method call from another method. I'm changing it. It's inside a DAO class which extends spring's HibernateDaoSupport class.

Answer (score 0):

There could be either of two problems:

1. You might be adding a *transient* User from out of your HttpSession, not a valid persistent instance/ from the current session. Make sure the ID/primary key of the User is set correctly, and/or try retrieving it within your current session.
2. Adding entities to an "inverse" relationship does not store relationships in the database, only the "master" side of the relationship does so. It does not look like you have defined as inverse here, but this is something to be aware of.